# jqGrid trims multiple spaces

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid displaying local data. The RoutingID column has multiple spaces in the source data – but when rendered in the jqGrid it has only one space before the character “54”.

Is there a way to display the data in the Grid as it is in the source – maintaining the same spaces in the source?

```
var data =[{"__type":"MyWebNoCompile.Routing","RoutingID":"C161-58          54","Destinations":"11 - My INC.-OUTER"},{"__type":"MyWebNoCompile.Routing","RoutingID":"C161-90B         54","Destinations":"11 - MY INC.-OUTER"}]
             alert(data);

            $("#grid").jqGrid({
                datastr: data,
                datatype: "jsonstring",
                colNames: ['Routing ID', 'Destinations'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'RoutingID', index: 'RoutingID', width:150 },
                    { name: 'Destinations', index: 'Destinations', width:400 }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                height: "auto",
                loadonce: true
            });
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [Custom Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)
2. [Predefined Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter)

[image]

**UPDATE**

Solved by adding a custom formatter as shown below

```
function mySpacePreserveFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
   {
             return '<pre>' + cellvalue + '</pre>';
   }
```

and using it as

```
name: 'RoutingID', index: 'RoutingID', formatter:mySpacePreserveFormatter
```

About `pre` tag from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

> The  tag defines preformatted text. Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Comment: there are exist `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { white-space: pre; }` rule in `ui.jqgrid.css` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L38) for example). It's unclear why you have the described problem. Probably you have some conflicts with other CSS files included on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML by specification strips out additional spaces - this is not a jQuery issue.

To keep whitespace, you may wrap the content in `<pre>` tags

Comment: or alternatively set `white-space: pre;` in css